# encodeURL() is not appending the Jsessionid

Tags: servlets, url-rewriting, jsessionid

```
String s = response.encodeURL("target.jsp");
System.out.println(s);
```

It is printing only `target.jsp` on console

But it should print

```
target.jsp;JSESSIONID=some id...
```

I am using WildFly server with Eclipse luna.

Comment: Do you have a `session`?

Comment: disable cookies in the browser